# Cloud SQL instance not connecting via Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I am trying to connect to an CloudSQL instance via Cloud Run but whenever I send a POST request the logs for the cloud run instance report:

> Cloud SQL instance "INSTANCE_NAME" is not reachable. Deploy a new revision adding the Cloud SQL connection. See documentation: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run

and followed by

> Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/INSTANCE_NAME at Query._callback (/app/index.js:65:35)

I have followed the documentation and added a public ip connection to my Cloud SQL instance as 0.0.0.0/0 and I added an sql connection to the instance via cloud console update command.

[image: connections]

I have also added SQL Admin and SQL Client permissions to all my service accounts and enabled the SQL Admin extension.

When I run my code locally via TCP and I am able to send a POST request as well.

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
  const dbSocketPath = process.env.DB_SOCKET_PATH || "/cloudsql";

  pool = mysql.createPool({
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    //      host:<instance-public-ip> //<- works locally
    //      port:3306
    socketPath: `${dbSocketPath}/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}`,
  });
}
```

I am all out of ideas, I think the socketpath `/cloudsql/` does not exist. Is there a way I can check if it exists?

Comment: What's your Cloud SQL engine and version?

Comment: Immediately remove the rule allowing 0.0.0.0/0. That is not required by Cloud Run and exposes your Cloud SQL instance to the Internet.

Comment: @guillaume  My sql instance is using MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Are you using the instance name or the instance connection name? It should be in the format project:region:instance

Comment: I was using the correct instance connection name, I resolved the issue now, I deleted the instance and service and created a new service with the sql connection on creation.

Comment: I have in mind that's only possible with MySQL 8. But I find nothing in the documenation. Can you have a try?

Comment: @USER149372 Would you mind to post your solution as a formal answer to help other users that have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment by @USER149372, this issue could be resolved by:

> delete the instance and service and create a new service with the SQL connection on creation.

This after ensured that the correct instance connection name is used whith the following format (as pointed out by @ kurtisvg)

> project:region:instance